# Find $\frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$ for implicit function $f$

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-function-theorem

How to find a formula for the second partial derivative of an implicit function

$\frac{\partial^2 f_i}{\partial x_j \partial x_k}$

Could not find any reference to this?

Comment: there is no absolutely general algorithm to do this. There are patterns of solving this problem. Usually one considers both y as a function of x and vice-versa and differentiate formally. 

Do you have a specific example in mind so we can show you how it is done?

Comment: No, it is just a general question I received. But if I can compute $f_x$ and $f_{xx}$ why not this?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you have (I specialise to $i=n+1$) 
$$F(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n,f_{n+1}(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n))=0$$
and would like to express the partial derivatives of $f_{n+1}$ in terms of those of $F$?

If so, let's write $f_{n+1}=f$ for simplicity.

By the Chain Rule we now have on differentiating w.r.t. $x_j$ that
$$F_j+F_{n+1}f_j=0$$
which expresses each $f_j$ in terms of the partials of $F$.

Now differentiate this w.r.t. $x_k$, using Chain Rule (and Product Rule)
to get
$$F_{jk}+F_{j,n+1}f_k+F_{n+1,k}f_j+F_{n+1, n+1} f_j f_k +F_{n+1}f_{jk}=0.$$

It is now tedious algebra to substitute for the $f_j$ and extract an expression for $f_{jk}$.

Comment: can you please explain the product(chain) rule u used in more detail?

Comment: And can you check your indices? Im confused about $f_j$, $f_{n+1}$...

Comment: Before I do that, please can you write explicitly what you mean by the Implicit Theorem here. I think I may have misunderstood and only dealt with the 1-diml case. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I think this happened here. I meant  the general case

Comment: Ah, I see I will have to try again.